# Python requsts.post returning 405 error: The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, xml

Howdie do,

I'm just running a simple flask API call.

The flask API will take a XML request in and then parse the XML and print it to the terminal screen.

However, everytime I do this, I'm receiving

> The method is not allowed for the requested URL

The Flask script is:

```
__author__ = 'Jeremy'
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import xmltodict

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def parsexml():

    xmlrequest = xmltodict.parse(request.data)

    print xmlrequest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The script that sends the XML is:

```
__author__ = 'Jeremy'

import requests

xml = """
<dtc:GetShipmentUpdates>
 <dtc:GetShipmentUpdatesRequest>
    <dtc:SearchStartTime>2015-07-12T12:00:00</dtc:SearchStartTime>
    <dtc:SearchEndTime>2015-07-12T12:30:00</dtc:SearchEndTime>
 </dtc:GetShipmentUpdatesRequest>
</dtc:GetShipmentUpdates> """

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', data=xml, headers=headers)

print r.content
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and if so, how can I send a POST request to my flask application running on 127.0.0.1:5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from `parsexml`. Try returning some content:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def parsexml():
    xmlrequest = xmltodict.parse(request.data)
    print xmlrequest
    return "Thanks for the data!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Howdie do,

You can't send POST requests to /

So I changed it to go to the following:

```
__author__ = 'Jeremy'
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import xmltodict

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def say_hello():
    return "Say goodbye Jeremy"

@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def parsexml():
    xmlrequest = xmltodict.parse(request.data)
    return xmlrequest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int("80"))
```

Work now

Comment: You can send `POST` requests to `/`.